# DescribeProcess response in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

The Encoding and the Schema tag for ComplexData in a DescribeProcess-Response document is an optional parameter (defined in the WPS Specification).
In GeoServer, the Response document doesn't contain these parameters.
Also, for a literal input parameter, the parameter "DataType" isn't shown.

What do I have to change in GeoServer, that these parameters are shown in the response document? (Respectively, how can I edit the parameters?)

Thanks for helping.